# aws api gateway client certificate: certificate is empty

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, certificate, client, gateway

We are using aws api gateway to call our backend api. We used aws generated client cert to call end point (.net web api).

But each time the request comes in, I did not see any cert in the raw data. below is the raw data:

```
GET /rest/test
x-amzn-apigateway-api-id: xxxxxxxx
x-api-key: xxxxxxx
User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: 24.16.156.224
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5a6a4c29-07091e853bae0bbd7f7db3b3
accept: */*
Host: 185b5418.ngrok.io
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: 52.42.18.220
```

Comment: The cert info isn't in the "raw data."  It's used to negotiate TLS with your web server, which needs to autheticate it and then optionally provide the cert info to the application.  I would not expect that this would work through ngrok unless they support mutual auth.  Do they?

Comment: After spending some time, I figure something out but we decide to choose a different approach. Thanks for your info. For Cert to be readable on the server end, request has to be https and I did get it working with my test client with ngrok.